# Probability of $X$ > $Y$, given $X$, $Y$ being the maximum of distinct Normal Distribution Families

Tags: normal-distribution, statsmodels

Let
$
\begin{matrix}
X_i & \sim & N(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2) \\ 
Y_i & \sim & N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2) \\ 
X & := & \max(X_i, i \in \{ 1,2, ..., n_X\}) \\ 
Y & := & \max(Y_i, i \in \{ 1,2, ..., n_Y\})
\end{matrix}
$

What is $\mathbb{P}[X>Y]$, as a function of $( \mu_X, \sigma_X, n_X, \mu_Y, \sigma_Y, n_Y )$?

Comment: You presumably wish to assume  that $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Comment: One easy case is $$P[X>Y]=\Phi\Big(\frac{\mu_X-\mu_Y}{(\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2)^{1/2}}\Big) \text { if } n_X=n_Y=1$$ One harder case is $\mu_X=\sigma_X=\sigma_Y$ and $\mu_Y=0$, for which there is a relevant answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/550015

Answer (score 0):

$Pr(X>Y)=\sum_{k=1}^{n_x}Pr(X_k>max\{Y_i\}, X_k=max\{X_i\})$

$Pr(X_k>max\{Y_i\}, X_k=max\{X_i\})=\int_{x_k}Pr(x_k>max\{Y_i\}, x_k=max\{X_i\})f_X(x_k)dx_k=\int_{x_k}Pr(Y_1<x_k)^{n_y}Pr(X_1\leq x_k)^{n_x-1}f_X(x_k)dx_k=\int_{x_k}\Phi(\frac{x_k-\mu_y}{\sigma_y})^{n_y}\Phi(\frac{x_k-\mu_x}{\sigma_x})^{n_x-1}f_X(x_k)dx_k$

Thus
$Pr(X>Y)=\sum_{k=1}^{n_x}\int_{x_k}\Phi(\frac{x_k-\mu_y}{\sigma_y})^{n_y}\Phi(\frac{x_k-\mu_x}{\sigma_x})^{n_x-1}f_X(x_k)dx_k$, where $f_X()$ is the density of $X_i$ and will depend on $\mu_x,\sigma_x$.